# Outlook 2010 email fixed width issue

Tags: email, outlook, width, installation

I have an html email .oft (Outlook File Template) created in Outlook 2010 with a table layout width set to 600px. This ecard template is distributed to others at the company who might want to add a few lines of texts and signature to the bottom after the table. 
However all the added text appears on the top right next to the table. How can I either block any content on the right of the table or set the width of the email to be only 600px so any new additions will appear correctly at the bottom after the table? I know that floats and clear css don't work reliably across in html emails. 
Thanks, Attila

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to create a table at 100% width.  Inside that table, make two cells, one with a width of 600, and another with a width of 'auto'.  THis will then span the full remaining width of the email window.

This is not an ideal situation, but as you have mentioned, there are very tight limitations on what is achievable in MS Outlook 2010, let alone 2007.

Something like this:

```
<table><tr>
<td width="600">Enter details here</td>
<td> &nbsp; (space character so no client disregards this cell) </td>
</tr></table>
```

You may need to experiment with the width of that last cell, you could try and make it 100% or something to force the take up of all extra space on the right, but it will come down to your code, and your email, and what works best for that organization.

If that doesn't work, consider a nested table inside the first table to be extra sure...

```
<table width="100"><tr>
   <td width="100%">
     <table width="600"><tr>
       <td width="600">Enter details here</td>
     </tr></table>
   </td>
   <td>&nbsp;(space character so no client disregards this cell) </td>
</tr></table>
```

As a guide - I use the Campaign Monitor reference for compatibilities:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ - download the XLS file on that page.

Good luck.